# Reusing a WordPress.com blog address that was deleted

Tags: wordpress.com

I have deleted my primary WordPress blog. When I open this deleted blog it shows the  message

> xyz.wordpress.com is no longer available.

(Consider my login to WordPress.com as xyz).

Now when I want to create a new blog using the same blog address, it is showing this error

> Sorry, that site already exists!

How can I recover my address?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly, gone is gone.

> [Addresses (URLs) for blogs that have been deleted by the owner will remain deleted.](http://en.support.wordpress.com/recycling-blog-names/)

Even if you were the one to delete it and want it back, you can't. There should be a few warning screens about what will happen if you do delete a blog.